# How to check the array is of how many dimension in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example I have an array as follows & expected output is given.

In javascript how can we determine dynamically how many levels are there in my array `ary`.

```
var ary = ["a","b",["c","d"],"e",["f","g",["h","i"],"j"]];
Output: 3


var ary = ["a","b",["c","d"],"e",["f","g","i"]];
Output: 2


var ary = ["a","b",["c",["d"]],"e",[["f","g",["i","j"]],"k"]];
Output: 4
```

Comment: I'd recommend writing a recursive loop that goes through each item in the array, and if it is an array recurses into that array (and so on), increasing a `currentDepth` and a `maxDepth` variable.  Every time you exit a level of recursion decrement `currentDepth` but keep `maxDepth`.  `maxDepth` is only increased if the `currentDepth` is greater than it.  When you're done, `maxDepth` should be the deepest nested "dimension" in your array.

Comment: first creat var dim = 0. then iterate with for loop in every for loop check instance of Array and if it would be true add  ++ to dim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array's depth in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420156/get-arrays-depth-in-javascript)

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13814621/8657746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reccursive function that will traverse through the depths of the array and track the maximum of it. Note that the tracking is done via properties attach to the function itself.

```js
var ary1 = ["a","b",["c",["d"]],"e",[["f","g",["i","j"]],"k"]];



function getDimension(arr, start) {

  //Attach depth tracking properties to the function
  if (start){
    getDimension.depth = 0;   
    getDimension.maxDepth = 0;   
  }
    

  //Track max depth
  getDimension.depth++
  if (getDimension.depth > getDimension.maxDepth)
    getDimension.maxDepth++;  

  //Manage recursion
  for (let element of arr)
    if (element instanceof Array)
       getDimension(element);

  getDimension.depth--;  
  
  //In first level at this point
  if (getDimension.depth === 0)
     return getDimension.maxDepth;  

}

let d = getDimension(ary1, true);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, because the depth is cached as a property on the function itself and it is never cleared, this will always report the max depth as the max depth of _any_ array it has _ever_ been passed, not necessarily the array that it has _currently_ been passed.  It essentially can't be reused.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Very true! Thanks for pointing this out. Answer edited.